# Вывод strace ( si_code )

Tags: linux

Почему при получении SIGPIPE в выводе strace ( si_code == SI_USER )?

```
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=40000, si_uid=800} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

Выдержка из man страницы strace.

```
Signals are printed as signal symbol and decoded siginfo structure.  
An excerpt  from  stracing  and interrupting the command "sleep 666" is:

sigsuspend([] <unfinished ...>
    --- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=...} ---
    +++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

Выдержка из man страницы системного вызова sigaction.

```
For a regular signal, the following list shows the values which can be placed 
in si_code for any signal, along with the reason that the signal was generated.
        SI_USER 
               kill(2).
```

Но я не вижу в выводе strace системного вызова kill. Почему ( si_code == SI_USER )?

Comment: дык, `kill()`, наверняка, вызывается из другого процесса, не трассируемого `strace`'ом…

Comment: @Fat-Zer  Кем он вызывается? Подозрение на оболочку? Я запускал процесс и устанавливал обработчик на дефолт. Кто в таком случае присылает сигнал? Это всё равно делает ядро. Почему ( si_code == SI_USER )? `perl -E '$SIG{"PIPE"} = "DEFAULT" ;  say "TEST"' | :`

Comment: что именно и как ты отлаживаешь? без информации, как это поведение воспроизвести можно долго гадать…

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я ничего не отлаживаю. Изучаю инструмент администраторов strace. В одном окне запустил `perl -E '$SIG{"PIPE"} = "DEFAULT" ; sleep 60 ; say "TEST"' | :` в другом прицепился к процессу с помощью strace. Чтобы я не делал ( si_code == SI_USER ). Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Ничего особого примечательного здесь нет: просто документация несколько неполна. При системном вызове `kill()` в `siginfo_t` всегда будет `si_code==SI_USER`, но обратное, вообще говоря, неверно: сигнал с  `si_code==SI_USER` может быть послан и при других событиях в самом процессе, в частности, при вызовах `raise()` и `abort()` или, например, как здесь, при попытке записи в сломанную трубу. Единственное что, в отличии от сигнала с `SI_KERNEL`, он обеспечивает установку корректных значений в поля `si_pid` и `si_uid`.

POSIX также явно [допускает](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/signal.h.html) подобное поведение.

Comment: Мне кажется, что код `SI_USER` используется, когда сигнал вызван  действиями в user-space, а другие коды явно не подходят (по крайней мере такое мнение сложилось у меня при внимательном разглядывании перечня значений `si_code` в [man sigaction](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) и беглом взгляде на пару мест в сорсах ядра)

Comment: @avp, я тоже по верхам посмотрел, когда-как ядро его использует и у меня тоже такое впечатление возникло, но утверждать я это не решился т.к. ИМХО это всё равно как-то странно, что сигнал вручную посланный `kill()`'ом оказывается неотличимым от того, что вызывается действиями процесса; почему бы не использовать `SI_KERNEL`, раз уж его добавили — он кажется более логичным выбором; в общем всё это у меня как-то формализовать не получается… тут могут быть и какие-то случайные исторические причины и какая-то подковёрная совместимость с другими системами… в общем тут как-то сложно раскопать что-то…